# SQL how to change string from eg. 01/06/2012 to 2012-06-01

Tags: sql, string

I have a table `table_a` with the column `field_b` which format is string.

In that field their is written e.g. `01/06/2012`.

I need to change it to `2012-06-01`

I cannot change fields type etc.

Comment: You should not store dates in character columns in the first place.

Comment: In dealing with dates you should use the date datatype because this gives you more problem if you use char..

Comment: db is not mine i can't chage a thing in there. usually its not date htat stored there... but this time my work required that i store date in exactly that field....

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most SQL engines have a substring() function. Use that together with concat() to create the new string:

(pseudocode)

```
update table_a set field_b=concat(substring(field_b, 6, 4), '-', substring(field_b, 3, 2), '-', substring(field_b, 0, 2))
```

Refer to your SQL server's manual for details.

Comment: thnx this helped, i also wanted to ask 1 more thing if i have format date yyyy-mm-dd eg.2012-08-10 but day and month are writen in worng places how do i make 2012-10-08 the format leaves same yyyy-mm-dd. thnx in advance.

Comment: Just flip the last two substring() calls:

  concat(substring(field_b, 6, 4), '-', substring(field_b, 0, 2), '-', substring(field_b, 3, 2))

Refer to the SQL server's manual for how the substring() and concat() functions work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(DATEtime,'01/06/2012',103))
```

> For more examples [Click here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(cast('01/06/2012' as DATE) as varchar(10))
```

Comment: `select cast(cast('01/06/2012' as DATETIME) as varchar(10))` returns _"Jun  1 201"_ on SQL-Server 2005 (no _Date_ datatype) here in germany.

Comment: Doesn't that have localization issues? In the US it would be 6th of January, in Europe first of June.

Comment: thing is there is like couple of thousnads differnet dates not 1 of them and i need to change all of them not just 01/06/2012. but all dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in db.

Comment: @Buar: That is just an example, then you only have to replace `01/06/2012` with your date-varchar column, for example: `select cast(cast(MyColumn as DATE) as varchar(10)) FROM MyTable`

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(datetime,'01/06/2012',103)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update [YourDB].[dbo].[YourTable]
set [YourColumn] =  convert(nvarchar(10), convert(datetime,[YourColumn]), 126)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer that will work and will avoid localization issues:

```
select cast(cast(convert(DATETIME, '01/06/2012', 103) as DATE) as NVARCHAR(10))
```

You need to use 103 as format, then convert it to date (to cut off the time) and then convert it to varchar.